# How can I tell that an integer is only 2 digits long?

Tags: java, int

I need to write a Java program that prompts the user to enter an integer consisting of exactly 2 digits; then displays on the screen the sum of its individual digits.

I am stuck here. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

public class ss {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);

       int x;

       System.out.println("Please Enter a number consists of 2 digits only : ");

       x = input.nextInt();
       x.length() == 2;
   }
}
```

and the last line contains an error!

Comment: the last line isn't exactly a proper statement

Comment: change your title to actually reflect your question.

Comment: @Adel: and it evens calls a method on a primitive type which is not supposed to respond to `length()`

Comment: DO you consider that "01" is a vlid entry or not?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that `x` is positive, a simple way to check if it has exactly two digits would be:

```
if (x >= 10 && x <= 99) {
    // x contains exactly two digits
}
```

Comment: No completely correct what if x was -88? it is an two digits integer you need one line above it: x = x > 0 ? x: -1 * x;

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` is of type `int`, so you can't call a method on it.  You need to either read the input as a `String` or convert the `int` to a `String` then call `length()`, or just test that the `int` is between `10` and `99`, inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

In a programming langauge, there are things called L-values and R-values.  In an assignment operation, a L-value can accept a R-value as input.  This comes from the typical layout which has L-values on the left of the assignment operator and R-values on the right side of the assignment operator.

```
x = 5;
```

x is the L-value and 5 is the R-value.  It is possible to assign five to x.

However, a function returns a R-value.  Therefore, it is possible to do this

```
x = a.length();
```

but is is not possible to do

```
a.length() = x;
```

because you can not assign a value to the return of a function.

Fundamentally, L-values are *names* which represent a *value*, but R-values are *values* or items which when analyzed result in the return of *values*.

Now, if you used the equals comparison operator, both values must be R-values, because no assignment is being performed

```
a.length == x
```

is just fine, because it is not the assignment operator `=` but rather one of the comparison operators `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes because `x` is a primitive, not an object. Only objects have methods like `length()`. A quick an easy way to determine the length of an integer is by using `Math.log()`.

```
public int length(int n){
    if (n == 0) return 1; // because Math.log(0) is undefined
    if (n < 0) n = -n; // because Math.log() doesn't work for negative numbers
    return (int)(Math.log10(n)) + 1; //+1 because Math.log10 returns one less
                                     //than wanted. Math.log10(10) == 1.
}
```

This method uses the fact that the base b logarithm of an integer a is related to the length of the integer a.

Or, if you don't know how to use methods, you could do this (assuming n is the integer to check):

```
int length = (n == 0)? 1: ((n > 0)? (int) (Math.log(n)) + 1: (int) (Math.log(-n)) + 1);
```

Or, if you don't use the ternary operator, you could expand it:

```
int length = -1; //placeholder; might not need it.
if (n == 0) length = 1;
else if (n > 0) length = (int) (Math.log(n)) + 1;
else length = (int) (Math.log(-n)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the length of an `int` by calling a method on it, but you can find the length of a `String`.

Try converting the `int` to a `String` and finding the length of that:

```
boolean isTwoDigits = x.toString().length() == 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call length on integer just write

```
if(x>=10 && x<=99)
{
//write your code here
}
```

Comment: What if int is a negative number? I suggest you to update your answer by using `java.lang.Math.abs()`